# Fixing SQL Server format date in Laravel

Tags: sql-server, laravel

I using Laravel 7 and database SQL Server 2017, I have date format in my database like this

[image]

Date format stored in database: 2020-08-10

My problem is when I get the date in Laravel project I get this format change like this: Jan 20 2020 12:00:00:AM

My code is

```
$ratingSession = RatingSession::first();
        return $ratingSession['pk_date'];
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: What is the column definition in SQL Server - `varchar` or`date`?

Comment: I define colum type date

Comment: So a column type of `date` doesn't not have a format as such, its just a date. However you are seeing the format in your database is just the default way that your database client (SSMS?) displays it. When you pull it into Laravel either its being automatically converted to a string OR you are again just seeing the default format. I don't know whether Laravel supports native date objects but if it does stuff it into one of those. If it doesn't you might want to make use of the SQL function `format` to force the format of the date.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to use [Carbon](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/). It is included with Laravel.

```
return \Carbon\Carbon::parse($ratingSession['pk_date'])->format('Y-m-d');
```

If you always want to have it in this format you can use [date casting](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-mutators#date-mutators) in your Model:

```
class RatingSession extends Model
    /**
     * The attributes that should be mutated to dates.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $dates = [
        'pk_date',
    ];

    /**
     * The storage format of the model's date columns.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $dateFormat = 'Y-m-d';
```

Comment: That's can't fix my problem, i can convert date what ever I want. but my problem is I can't use query Where pk_date doesn't work

Comment: @achmadsyarippudin your question asks nothing about that. Update your question.